# Wish to add numbers to word/url

Tags: command-line, scripting, numbering

What i want;

as of example- Youtube.com/1
i wish to have an automated script that counts up to a 1000

> URL EXAMPLE: 
>   https://www.youtube.com/1
>   https://www.youtube.com/2

Edit: ---

[Fetching user title]

Seen a post prior of someone posting how to do it by single account

> wget -qO- 'http://www.twitter.com/9' |
>    perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /\s*(.*?)(?: - twitter)?\s*</title/si'

I wish to do this from the range 1-1000 and have it output to >> .txt

Comment: Any attempts / ideas / thoughts from your side? Some more details like OS and shell versions were desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use embeded bash sequencing.

```
echo https://youtube.com/{1..1000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
#!/bin/bash
# script used to call URL up to 1 a 1000
URL="https://www.youtube.com"
for i in {1..1000}
do
  #Enter Command what you want here
   /usr/bin/curl "$URL/$i"
   wget -qO- $URL/$i" >> filename.txt 
done
```